# Weaving with EclipseLink fails with NPE

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

Performing weaving (static or dynamic) results in the following error:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.1.v20171221-bd47e8f): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [MyUnit] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:231)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Project.hasSQLResultSetMapping(Project.java:1040)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.queries.NamedNativeQueryMetadata.hasResultSetMapping(NamedNativeQueryMetadata.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.queries.NamedNativeQueryMetadata.process(NamedNativeQueryMetadata.java:172)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processQueries(MetadataProject.java:1713)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.addNamedQueries(MetadataProcessor.java:153)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2024)
```

I didn't get this error with EclipseLink 2.6.5 and if I turn Weaving off everything works fine. 
Is there a way to work around it? What triggers the error?

Comment: since the method is called "hasSQLResultSetMapping", do you perhaps have a `@SqlResultSetMapping` on some class?! and if so then why not post it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NPE is a bug, as it isn't performing a null check and throwing a more specific error: This error could only occur if you've specified a named native (SQL) query on your entities that references a SqlResultSetMapping, but you haven't defined any result sets mappings.  See https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Native#SQL_Result_Set_Mapping for documentation and an example.

Comment: We do have a few named native queries with specified mappings, but all these mappings have a corresponding SqlResultSetMapping annotation on an entity class. Can the fact that queries specified in orm.xml and mappings by annotations cause the problem?

Comment: If one isn't being loaded, yes.  The error only can happen if there aren't SQLResultSetMappings found yet in the context, as the collection is null and would have been initialized if there were.  So how ever you have defined them, they weren't loaded. Turn on logging to finest and check the classes as they get processed to find out why.

Comment: According to the log, EclipseLink does not scan Java classes at all during static weaving. Moving mappings from code to the orm.xml solves the problem. However, it is not clear to me why annotations ignored.

Comment: It only picks up classes for weaving that are mentioned in the persistence.xml. If you might try explicitly naming your class within it rather than having it get picked up from the class path: entity look up was only meant for within containers - it is provider specific outside a container, requires enabling as the default for the <exclude-unlisted-classes> flag is different in a container then when running outside it (such as when compiling).

Comment: After I listed all the entities (just class names) in the orm.xml it started loading them with all the existing annotations. For example: <entity class="com.company.EmployeeEntity" />